# SSRS Report - Create CSV file from query that already returns CSV string

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I am evaluation solutions to a relatively unique problem or use case of SSRS Reports. I would like to be able to use the scheduling component of SSRS Reporting to create a CSV file from a query that already returns the data in CSV format. The reason behind this idea is that I am looking to have dynamic columns (both which columns are selected as well as the order they are in). From a decent amount of research doing this is a table/tablix format didn't seem viable. Not to mention the columns that are hidden with an expression end up showing up in the CSV anyway.

So the main requirements are:

1. Use of SSRS for scheduling
2. Allowing for dynamic column return (number of columns and order).

Comment: I think you'd be better off using SQL Agent Job to schedule and run the report, you'll be able to make your results as dynamic as you wish.

Comment: @NewGuy This would entail something like scheduling a job which takes the user's query (this is the dynamic part) and runs that on a schedule or once. Is that the jist of the solution, or do I have the wrong ideal?

Comment: That's correct, Use SQL Server Agent to execute send_db_mail  and attach results as attachment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017